# Are there any suitable APIs in writing chrome extension to download images behind cookie authentication?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension which let me grab image links and download them on certain web pages. So if the images need basic authentication, for example username and password login, even I have already successfully logged in and got the correct image's url, my codes still can only download a 'protective' picture instead the right one as If I were logged out. Please let me know how can I get the correct one ?

I have tried several ways to achieve this:

1. Use `chrome.downloads.download` and it just gives me above result.
2. Then I tried to bind a header which contains cookie I successfully logged in with, result remains same. I also got an error in Chrome extension, which says `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Unsafe request header name`. I guess this is not allowed in such situation.
3. Besides chrome.downloads.download, I also tried `chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename` which gives me same result.

background.js

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  let scriptCode =
    `(function() {
      return document.cookie;
    })();`
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: scriptCode}, function(cookies_result){
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: "http://www.sample.com/abc/sample.jpg",
      filename: "Pictures/new.jpg",
      conflictAction: 'overwrite',
      headers: [
        {name: "Cookie", value: cookies_result[0]},
      ],
    });
  });
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Batch Save",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Save multiple items",
  "page_action": {
    "default_title": "batch save images to ...",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/save_16.png",
      "32": "images/save_32.png",
      "48": "images/save_48.png",
      "128": "images/save_128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/save_16.png",
    "32": "images/save_32.png",
    "48": "images/save_48.png",
    "128": "images/save_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "downloads",
    "cookies"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

So I expect to use the API to download the correct image (in above instance `http://www.sample.com/abc/sample.jpg`, 300kb) when I have already logged in, not the wrong one(could be another smaller icon, like 1.gif, 50kb) which is shown for guests who are not logged in.

And also, since desired images are already displayed in browser, which means they are already transmitted and stored in some places (at least cache), is it possible to copy or save from somewhere locally or may grab the images on the fly while they arriving as binary data then save them, which avoids requesting other time on backend?

Comment: chrome.downloads API cannot set a `Cookie` header (it's [forbidden](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/http/http_util.cc?q=kForbiddenHeaderFields)) so you'll need to use normal XHR/fetch and chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders to add the header. Note, some servers may also want you to specify a `Referer` (one `r`) header.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you for your comment. I will give it a try.